# Django url testing

Tags: django, testing, django-urls

urls.py of my web application is as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('u/<int:unit_id>/', views.unit_view, name='unit_view'),
    path('u/<int:unit_id>/edit/', views.unit_edit, name='unit_edit'),
]
```

I tried to write test as following. Unable to run the tests. Not even getting errors

```
from django.urls import reverse, resolve


class TestUrls:

    def test_unit_view_url(self):
        path = reverse('unit_view', kwargs={'unit_id': 1})
        assert resolve(path).views.unit_view == 'unit_view'

    def test_unit_edit_url(self):
        path = reverse('unit_edit', kwargs={'unit_id': 1})
        assert resolve(path).views.unit_edit == 'unit_edit'
```

Comment: You did not subclass from `TestCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not subclass from `TestCase`, so for Django this is just an *ordinary* class.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse, resolve

class TestUrls(TestCase):

    def test_unit_view_url(self):
        path = reverse('unit_view', kwargs={'unit_id': 1})
        self.assertEqual('unit_view', resolve(path).views.unit_view)

    def test_unit_edit_url(self):
        path = reverse('unit_edit', kwargs={'unit_id': 1})
        self.assertEqual('unit_edit', resolve(path).views.unit_view)
```

Typically assertions are also written with [**`assertEqual(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) and friends, since this will produce helpful messages like:

```
AssertionError: 'foobar' != 'foobor'
- foobar
?     ^
+ foobor
?     ^
```

So then testing will print the two values, and - depending on the types and assertion - can even give more insight in what is going wrong.

For more information, see the [Django documentation on *Writing and running tests*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/).

Comment: Have done the above changes. Getting error as  Reverse for 'unit_view' not found. 'unit_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: @PrabhanjanVeeravilli: did you define a namespace? Did you installed the app? How do you run the tests?

Comment: @PrabhanjanVeeravilli: did you register the app where the `urls` are defined? Is there a path from the root urls, to your `urls.py`? Did you define a namespace?

Comment: @PrabhanjanVeeravilli: well the test itself is "working". I think you should look if there is something wrong with the URLs you registered, for example by accessing the URL, and see the debug message in the browser.